# Unable to inspect variable

Tags: perl, variables

I'm having a very difficult time inspecting the `$return` variable. The `print "return = ". $return ."\n";` always comes back blank even though the process is still running. I do receive a warning about uninitialized variable. Can someone please explain?

```
my $process="MInstaller";
my $return=` ps -eaf |grep $process | grep -v grep`;
sub chk_proc{
  print "in chk_proc\n";
  print "\n";
  print "return = ". $return ."\n";
  while ( my $return ne "" ) {
   sleep(5);
  };
};
```

Comment: Are you calling the `chk_proc()` routine from somewhere outside what you've posted?

Comment: Your while loop uses a `my $return ...` which is a new variable, and not referencing the `ps` backtick output.  Also, where you are doing your sleep loop, if you ever call chk_proc, it would loop infinitely, as you give no way for the `$return` variable to update within that scope.

Comment: The warning you're getting is with your `my $return ne ""`, in which `$return` is, by the preceding `my`, indeed a new variable which is compared against `""` before it has a value other than `undef`.  Remove the `my` to avoid that.

Comment: Running this code does not produce the warning you describe. Nowhere do you call the chk_proc function. And if you do call it, you will get an infinite loop of uninitialized warnings (assuming warnings are on), since $return is re-initialized on every iteration, and even if it weren't, it does not change within the loop.

Comment: @runrig, running this code sure should produce that warning.  `perl -lwe 'my $a = 2; x(); sub x { print $a; 1 while my $a ne ""; }'` --> `Use of uninitialized value $a in string ne ...`.

Comment: @JulianFondren - I know how to write code to get that warning, I was describing the OP's code.

Comment: You said _I do receive a warning about uninitialized variable_. Are you using `use warnings;`.

Comment: @runrig, the OP's code also produces the warning.  For exactly the same reason my snippet does.  Unless you run it without `use warnings`, which would be an odd thing to do as the OP stated that he received a warning.

Comment: @JulianFondren - No, your code actually calls a function.

Comment: Hey Julian, I took the my out as you suggested and it does grep the correct file but it sleeps forver eventhough I have it sleeping for 5 seconds (sleep(5)). thoughts? thanks. BTW, thanks for the explanations too!

Comment: Got it to work. Had to grep for the process in a different place in the code. thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

You're close. Your code doesn't works, because the variable `$return` in the

```
while ( my $return ne "" ) {
```

is another variable (declared in the scope of while) as your first `$return`.

You can try the next:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

chk_proc('[M]Installer'); #use the [] trick to avoid the 'grep -v grep :)

sub chk_proc{ while( qx(ps -eaf |grep $_[0]) ) {sleep 5} };
```

Comment: I used the code above but I'm receiving an error on the grep: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

Comment: @user1718586 just checked the script in two different systems and works. Are you sure than used exactly as above? becasuse the error looks like than your grep doesn't get the pattern so, your chk_proc call doesn't contain the checked program name. e.g. `[M]Installer`

Comment: so, I copied and pasted it again just to make sure. I changed the script name and still get the grep error. see below:          chk_proc('[M]apUserInstall'); #chk_proc('[M]apUserInstall'); #use the [] trick to avoid the 'grep -v grep :)

sub chk_proc{ while( qx(ps -eaf |grep $_[0]) )  {sleep 5} };

Answer (score 0):

- Are you using `use warnings;` and `use strict;`?
- What about using `pgrep` instead of `ps`?
- What happens if `$return` returns more than one line?

Your program would flow better if your subroutine merely checked to see if the process is running and you used that in another loop.

Here, my check process subroutine returns a list of all the processes it find. I can use this in my loop to see if the process itself has stopped. I could have used `qx()` to get a process list, then use `split` to create a list of processes.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    PROCESS => "MInstaller",
    SLEEP   => 5,
};

while ( process_check( PROCESS ) ) {
    say qq(Process ) . PROCESS . qq( is running...);
    sleep SLEEP;;
}
say qq(Process ) . PROCESS . qq( has ended.);

sub process_check {
    my $process = shift;
    open ( my $process_fh, "-|", "pgrep $process" );
    my @process_list;
    while ( my $line = <$process_fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        push @process_list, $line;
    }
    close $process_fh;
    return @process_list;
}
```